# Matching multiple encased strings in a single line

Tags: php, regex

`<!--:en-->Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March<!--:--><!--:it-->Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo<!--:-->`
This is the string that I want to match. I want to match the content inside the 2 HTML-like comment tags.

So I tried: `<!--:(..)-->(.+)<!--:-->` and some additional derivatives of this regex, but could not find a solution that returns the expected results. I also tried
`(|)` that checks if 2 such tags exist, but the results were unreliable, because it also needs to manage 3 matches or more.

This is the result from `preg_match`:

```
array(
0 => <!--:en-->Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March<!--:--><!--:it-->Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo<!--:-->
1 => en
2 => Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March<!--:--><!--:it-->Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo
)
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
array(
0 => <!--:en-->Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March<!--:--><!--:it-->Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo<!--:-->
1 => en
2 => Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March
3 => it
4 => Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo
)
```

EDIT:
The answer suggests using `preg_match_all();`
The resulting array is a bit different but the form is even more practical than the other one.

```
array(
0=>array(
  0=><!--:en-->Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March<!--:-->
  1=><!--:it-->Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo<!--:-->
)
1=>array(
  0=>en
  1=>it
)
2=>array(
  0=>Motodays 2014, 6.-9. of March
  1=>Motodays 2014, 6-9 Marzo
)
)
```

Comment: preg_match _all - instead of just preg_match

Comment: Change this `(.+)` to `([^<]+)`  - not the opening chevron. - but you could use non-greed too as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.+)` is greedy and goes until the last match. I would recommend adding a `?` to make it non-greedy. I also would use `preg_match_all`.

I think:

```
<!--:([a-z]{2})-->(.*?)<!--:-->
```

will achieve what you want.

https://regex101.com/r/tMN6km/1/